# Magento2 2.0.7 enterprise - Menu Override is just showing a blank page after adding a simple override

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides, topmenu

I'm just doing a simple override to modify the structure of the menu. But weird thing is after creating the module and just extending the topMenu. It just gives a blank page.

Here is my current code :

Registration.php :

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_SPMenu',
    __DIR__
    );
```

di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Vendor\SPMenu\Block\Html\SPMenu" />
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_SPMenu" setup_version="2.0.4">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

SPMenu/Block/Html

```
<?php 
/*** Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. 
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace SPCommerce\SPMenu\Block\Html;
class SPMenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu {

{
}
```

I just find it weird for such a simple task to have such an issue.

Hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: enable the developer mode from .htaccess you will get error that will help you to solve the problem

Comment: Does your config.php have your module entry exist over there? Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes it's already on developer mode, and module exists, because it's going to the file itself, I'm still investigating this, it might be a bug. I'm using enterprise 2.0.7, 2.1 might have no problem. I might try it.

Comment: Just a mistake with the namespace :D. Now it's working fine :D